# Do I NEED to supply a template for an Angular directive to wrap content?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I think I might be trying to fit a square peg into a round hole here. What I want to do is to define a convention for attaching some generic JavaScript functionality to a particular HTML attribute.

For example let's say I have this HTML:

```
<nav my-nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="tab">1</li>
    <li class="tab">2</li>
    <li class="tab">3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

My (very primitive) understanding of Angular is that I should create a directive. From [the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), I can see that since I want to wrap arbitrary content I need to use the `transclude` property. However, when I try that the elements inside my `<nav>` disappear.

From trial and error I see that Angular expects me to provide a `template` property to wrap the content. So I do that with a meaningless `<div>` tag, which feels quite superfluous to me.

```
myApp.directive('myNav', function() {
  return {
    // I get why this is necessary
    transclude: true,

    // I get why this is necessary
    link: function(scope, element) {
      // This is where my custom JavaScript logic goes
    }

    // This feels unnecessary to me
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
  };
});
```

Am I going against the grain here? Is there a more idiomatic way to do this with Angular? Should I not even bother doing this with Angular (i.e., would the standard approach be to just write custom JavaScript "outside" Angular for this purpose)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a directive is the Angular way to handle DOM manipulation.

But if you just want to add event listeners to some html you don't need to worry about transclusion.

For instance, here's a demo that adds a click listener (which you could, of course, easily instead watch for mouseover, etc...) to the attached dom element and to each of your `li` elements (just for demo purposes):

```
myApp.directive('myNav', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element) {
        // Add event listener to whole dom element
        element.bind('click', scope.clicked); 

        // Individual event listeners on each li element
        liElems= element.find("li");
        for (i = 0;i<liElems.length;i++)
          angular.element(liElems[i]).bind('click', scope.clicked); 
    }
  };
});
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5VZN/4/)

Comment: I don't want to add HTML to wrap around content; rather, I want to just interact with the HTML that's already there (i.e., without it getting erased). In other words I basically don't want to touch the HTML, just incorporate some JavaScript. Does that make sense?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you'd like the javascript to do?

Comment: Add some event listeners, for example.

Comment: Oh sure, while you'd probably want to use `ng-click` in my example here- is this the kind of thing you want to do: http://jsfiddle.net/b5VZN/2/

Comment: Interesting! So it looks like I don't need to use `transclude` at all, then?

Comment: Not if you just want to add something like event listeners.  Transclude comes into play, sometimes, when you're actually manipulating the dom.  Even then you don't always need transclusion

Comment: Yeah, I'll be doing more than *just* adding event listeners (manipulating visibility and CSS classes and such); but it sounds like this is the way to go for me, w/o transclusion. Thanks!

Comment: Check out the [angular element](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element) documentation.  It's got a list of the jQuery like methods available on element.

Answer (score 0):

#### You do not have to wrap it with a div, just use $transclude:

```
myApp.directive('myNav', function() {
  return {

    transclude: true,

    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl, $transclude) {
       $transclude(function(clone){
          element.append(clone);
       });
    }

  };
});
```

`ng-transclude` is just a **shortcut for simple cases**.

Comment: `$transclude` appears to be `undefined` when I follow your example exactly. Any hunch as to why that might be? (I'm using Angular 1.0.1 right now, it appears. Not tied to that version if I should upgrade.)

Comment: You should upgrade :> 1.2.8